# A thread of cloth is stuck to window?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

I want to describe a scene where someone has jumped out of the glass window, the windows is broken and threads of his cloths are "**stuck**" to broken window glasses.

What would be the correct verb for describing the threads that are left with window?

Should I say:

> His cloth threads were stuck to broken glass?

Or there are better verbs and phrases?

Comment: “Snagged on” or “caught on” might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The threads of [the victims]`s clothes remained behind, stuck to the shards of broken glass.

Something like that should work.